# JavaScript function does not work well on my hosting server

Tags: javascript, server

I have a problem with a javascript function. On my pc it works fine but on the my host's server it seems to work badly.

this function is in a React functional component which is a form for taking a quiz. This function displays a modal window with an error message if all the questions have not been answered. On my pc no problem but on the server even when the form is completely filled it displays this error modal.

here is the code that breaks the problem

```
for (let i = 0; i <= allQuestionsId.length - 1; i++) {
    !userQuestion.includes(allQuestionsId[i]) && 
    questionMissing.push(allQuestionsId[i])
}
```

I tested my userQuestion and allQuestionsId variables. They do contain the same data and therefore
questionMissing should not fill in because it is the one that triggers the error display if it is not empty.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't include irrelevant stuff in your posts.

Comment: As to your question, javascript runs in your browser and usually doesn't depend on the server. Things to check first:  1) all external scripts, if any, are properly loaded 2) all AJAX responses, if any, are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Ok thanks i will watch this